# How to get the present object in an Eclipse RCP view?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I'm starting with the coding of an Eclipse RCP and be relatively new to the RCP-World.

Currently i have **one perspective with two views**. One is a list with a **tableViewer** which shows a few names of workers.

The **second view is a "single view" with a few textboxes**. I use the **ISelectionListener** to notify when i have selected another entry in the list, so i can set the text boxes in the "single view" wiht the current selected worker objetc.

I didn't wrote the code on my own, and i used [this page (Vogella)](http://www.vogella.com/) to learn all the stuff behind RCP.

> My question is: **How can i get the current Object showed by the active view?** I mean, i have it
>   because of the SelectionListener, but i want to click on my own "save"
>   button to update changes to the object.

I want the object in the single view, so do i need another change listener, or is the object stored in the view and can i get it with the ISelection Interface?

> Can someone tell me in one or two sentences how it works? Or is it
>   just too simple, because i couldn't find anything elsewhere.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, but is not very easy, because the behaviour is not very standard. You are treating the two views as one usually deals with linked controls of a dialog or window. That's not necessarily wrong, but i smells bad (I cannot recall an example in the Eclipse IDE). Are you sure you are not confusing the roles of [Views and Viewers](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_the_difference_between_a_view_and_a_viewer?)? A View, in Eclipse, is a "Part" of a Workbench (you have basically Views and Editors), each view shows information and/or performs actions, but they are typically quite decoupled, you should be able open and close freely and independently each View, they rarely interact with each other directly (they typically display information or modify objects in the workspace). Further, you should not have a "Save" button in a View (again, look at the Eclipse IDE as an example), changes done throught a view [should be direct](http://wiki.eclipse.org/User_Interface_Guidelines#Views).

It is very doubtful for me that your design here in sound, perhaps you should instead use a single View, or a dialog. I suggest you to read more about [Views](http://wiki.eclipse.org/User_Interface_Guidelines#Views).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used this PDF http://www.ralfebert.de/eclipse_rcp/EclipseRCP.pdf (it's written in german). So i have to change my whole "architecture"? Can you recommend a good RCP Tutorial which describes everything? The eclipse framweork is quite huge. I know Java very "good", but this is a bunch of new stuff and it looks like it never ends...

Comment: Eclipse-RCP is quite huge and difficult to learn. Books like "Eclipse Plug-ins" (Clayberg Rubel) help. If you are not confortable with Java, then it must be really uphill (do you understand that Eclipse-RCP is a very particular and heavy-weight environment to do Java apps? are you sure you want to use it?)

Comment: Yeah, it's a study project, and we started with eclipse RCP without any knowledge what this is! ;) One month to go and the program must be ready, so i want to find a "quick" work-around to present the app and then maybe read a book about rcp and going deeper, because it looks like rcp uses good design patterns to deal with.